# How to filter duplicate id products taking in consideration other property using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a product array that I receive with some combinations.

Each combination can also have multiple combinations so in the array I receive all posibilities of every combination. I have a select in which I want to show all different posibilities and select by default the combination marked as default, but I do not want to show duplicate values.

I give an example:

```
[
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false, ....},
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false, ....},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': false, ....},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true, ....},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false, ....},
 ...
]
```

What I would like to get is another array that will be like this (just removing duplicate elements  - with same id_combination - that does not have `default:true` value).

```
[
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false, ....},
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false, ....},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true, ....},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false, ....},
 ...
]
```

I have tried using `map`, `filter`, `sort`... but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

I have to mention that the data that I receive from the back cannot be changed (as I do not have control about it).

How can I filter this array removing duplicated `id_combination` that does not have default property set to true?

*Note that if I have duplicated elements and none of them are set to default I also want to show at least one of them on the select (though they will not be selected by default).*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to remove duplicate elements with the same id_combination where its default value is set to false? So if the element is duplicated but its default value is true, you dont want to remove it?

Comment: @Hansel Exactly that, but if there are duplicated elements that none of them are set to default I want to have at least 1 of them to show on the select.

Comment: I have posted my solution. Take your time reading it

Comment: @FranciscoRomero I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
test = [
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false,},
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false,},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': false,},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true,},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': true},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false},
]

// sort by "id_combination" in ascending, and then by their "default" where  `false` first, then `true` second
sorted_test = test.sort((a, b) => {
    return a["id_combination"] - b["id_combination"] || (a["default"] - b["default"])
})


unique = [...new Map(sorted_test.map(item => [item["id_combination"], item])).values()]
console.log(unique)
```

Result:

```js
[ { id_combination: 15, default: false },
  { id_combination: 20, default: false },
  { id_combination: 30, default: true },
  { id_combination: 45, default: true } ]
```

Algorithm:

Sort them by their `id_combination` in ascending order, and also in their `default` key where `false` first, then `true` second.

Then, using `map`, it will eliminate duplicate key values where it only keep the last value inserted (which contains the default `true` if there is any).

PS: Sorry, my English is bad

Comment: @Francisco Romero, if my solution has actually answered your question, pls accept it so that people with the same problem can see my solution. Thank you

Comment: What would happen if their default property where set to true in the first place instead of the second one? And where do you indicate to `map` function that it will get the last value inserted? Many thanks!

Comment: @FranciscoRomero for your first question, it doesn't matter because sort will make sure that duplicated elements with default = false will always be first to be inserted. So if you have [{"id_combination": 1, default: true}, {"id_combination": 1, default: false}, {"id_combination": 1, default: true}], it's going to rearrange that in terms of their default value (False first, True second). If the sort function did not do it, map will fail.

Comment: As for your second question, map will eliminate the duplicate keys values, keeping only last inserted value of the same key. Remember that map keeps the order of insertion. So then, the `new Map(map_sorted_test)` will retrieve the original items but this time without duplicates. Then we use `spread operator` so as to create a newly fresh array without duplicates.

Comment: Technically, in a map, if you already have a key `default`, and you assign `false`, `false`, `true`, in that order, the last value you assigned will always be the value of that key.

Answer (score 1):

You can filtered out the duplicates with the help of [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

Demo **:**

```js
// Input array
const arr = [
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false},
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': false},
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true},
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false}
];

// creating an array which contains the 'id_combinations' property value coming from Input array.
const combinationIds = arr.map(obj => obj.id_combination);

// Filtering out the results with the help of .indexOf() and .lastIndexOf() 
const res = arr.filter(obj => (combinationIds.indexOf(obj.id_combination) === combinationIds.lastIndexOf(obj.id_combination)) || obj.default)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I only can mark 1 as accepted answer I upvote you too ^^

Comment: @FranciscoRomero That's totally fine  Just want to say that you have to accept the answers which is having good performance and easy implementation as well so that it help other developers as well who takes the reference from the accepted answers.

Comment: Yes, I know that. As you can see Im a user from 2016 or something like that and in the past I used to use it everyday. I prefered Hansel one because it was clearer to me than use indexOf and lastIndexOf. In this case I dont know what is the better in performance, though.

Comment: so I tried this because it looked like a clever an easy way, but indexOf will always return the first instance in an array. Meaning, it will just completely not show any values that have a duplicate. So if there is two duplicated items, this will remove both items instead of removing only one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

my preferred way of filtering duplicates is by first grouping array of item by ID iusing `array.reduce` method, and the result can be generated using either typical javascript Object or javascript Map

filtering duplicate using Object

```js
const arr = [
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true, },
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false, },
]

const uniqueIDObject = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if(current.default) accumulator[current.id_combination] = current

  accumulator[current.id_combination] ??= current
  return accumulator
}, {})

const uniqueArr = Object.values(uniqueIDObject)

console.log(uniqueArr)
```

filtering duplicate using Map

```js
const arr = [
 {'id_combination': 15, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 20, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': false, },
 {'id_combination': 30, 'default': true, },
 {'id_combination': 45, 'default': false, },
]

const uniqueIDMap = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if(accumulator.get(current.id_combination)?.default) return accumulator

  return accumulator.set(current.id_combination, current)
}, new Map())

const uniqueArr = [...uniqueIDMap.values()]

console.log(uniqueArr)
```